# How to open a collapse bar by onClick of an icon in another Component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a component `MockTable` which shows a list of some items in a table along with actions such as view, delete and update. I need to open a collapse bar in another component `AddMock` by clicking any of these actions in `MockTable`. These actions are icons. I'm using semantic-ui react and react-Bootstrap.

actions in `Mocktable` =>

```html
    <Icon link name="eye" />
    <Icon link name="edit" />
    <Icon link name="delete" />
```

AddMock =>

```html
const AddMock = () => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <Accordion style={{ paddingLeft: "32px" }}>
        <Card className="collapseStyle">
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              Add Mock
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              <Container className="mockbody">
                <Header as="h3">Hierarchy</Header>
                <TabContent />
              </Container>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

In the component that possess the actions `edit, view & delete`, you can declare a state variable `isActive` and pass it through props to the component `AddMock`.
Assuming `Mocktable.js` looks something like following.

**MockTable.js**:

```
const MockTable = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  
  return (
   <Icon link name="eye" onClick={()=>setIsActive(!isActive)} /> // this will act as toggle (show & hide)
   <Icon link name="edit" onClick={()=>setIsActive(!isActive)} />
   <Icon link name="delete" onClick={()=>setIsActive(!isActive)} /> 
   <AddMock isActive={isActive} />
  )
 }
```

**AddMock.js**

```
const AddMock = ({ isActive }) => {


return (
    <div className="row">
      <Accordion active={isActive} style={{ paddingLeft: "32px" }}>   // passing isActive here to show/hide.
        <Card className="collapseStyle">
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              Add Mock
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              <Container className="mockbody">
                <Header as="h3">Hierarchy</Header>
                <TabContent />
              </Container>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: in my case ```AddMock``` and ```MockTable``` are parent of ```MainContent```. And moreover when I  add this ```<AddMock isActive={isActive} />``` in ```MockTable``` , its rendering inside one of the cell in the table. How can I open Accordion dynamically by onClick on these actions. Eg: When I click ```<Icon link name="edit" onClick={()=>setIsActive(!isActive)} />``` , it should dymamically scroll down the page and open the Accordion.